# How to upload a file from a Unix server to a network drive using Putty?

Tags: ftp

I want to upload a file from a Unix Server to a network mapped drive using Putty. Now the Network Mapped drive (in Windows) holds an address something like \......... and is named MyDrive
I have been trying the following without any success

```
ftp <<Network Drive Address>>
```

but it says invalid address

```
user $USER $PASS
and then put ...
```

I have also tried something like scp

```
scp <<filename>> username@hostname<<address>>
```

But apparently it also does not do anything.

Is this the way should I do it ? Or am I missing something important down here ? Please explain.
Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You should use `WinSCP` (which runs on top of `putty`) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Use PSFTP, which is part of the PUTTY installation (PSFTP.EXE at the same folder).

You just enter `sftp <your_machine_ip>` and then use standard FTP commands to copy/paste files between hosts (`put <local_file>` to upload, `get <remote_file>` to download, etc.).

But if you want to connect to a shared drive, you probably need to use samba client like this:

`smbclient //computer_name/share_name -U <your_windows_user>`

Answer (score 0):

Use FileZilla

- Set the local site to be your network mapped drive
- Set the remote site to be the Un*x folder
- Drag the file from the remote site pane to the local site pane